# wpf calculate location of an control

Tags: c#, wpf, image

C# and wpf.
I have an ItemsControl that have many items(Images) and will load more if you scrolling down.

Is it possible to calculate location of an control in ItemsControl, when it's shown up?
Is there any existing event for this?

for example, ItemsControl has 200 items, and you seeing the first item.
is possible to know, when item 120 will be seen?

I want to create an smooth Image list control, so I can't show all items at once, so I thought this might be an good idea.

Comment: You mean smoother than [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), which is already in place when you use e.g. a ListBox?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to an image.Source,after we scrolling on them and it comes up, will be set. that's it

Comment: You should use both the UI and the data virtualization. Don't forget to load your images asynchronously. You could start reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls). Your question is actually an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't want to calculate location of a control, you want a smooth `ItemsControl` with images,

Comment: Another important thing to do when showing a large number of images in an ItemsControl is to limit the DecodePixelHeight or DecodePixelWidth of the BitmapImages used by the Image element in the ItemTemplate.